# How to use itextsharp in my classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic, itext

In my ASP web application, i need to convert my report as a PDF file. In my previous ASP.net application i have done it by using "itextsharp". Can anyone guide me how to use itextsharp to my Classic ASP application?

Answer (score 2):

In order to call a .NET class from classic ASP, it needs to be registered for COM interop. I don't believe iTextSharp supports that by default, but you could create a wrapper class that interacts with iTextSharp, and register *that* class for COM interop.

Creating classes in .NET that register themselves for COM interop is relatively straight-forward. Simply make sure the assembly is strong-named (i.e. that you sign it - on the project properties "Signing" tab, check the "Sign the assembly" checkbox and provide a strong name key file [or generate a new one]) and that you have the "Register for COM interop" checkbox checked on the "Build" page of the project properties.